# Java.net.UnknownHost Exception Android Download

Tags: android, networking, permissions, download

I am attempting to do a download in an asychronous task in android.  Unfortunately I am getting an "unknownHost' error.  To me it looks like I have the proper permissions but I am still getting this error.  Below is my permissions, my error, and the function.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Craig

```
  11-27 21:51:34.545: D/ImageManager(9381): Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: 

        public void downloadFromUrl(String strUrl, String fileName) { // this is the downloader
        // method
        try {
            File parentDirectory= new File(PATH);
            if (!parentDirectory.exists()) {
                System.err
                        .println("It seems like parent directory does not exist...");
                if (!parentDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                    System.err.println("And we cannot create it...");
                    // we have to return, throw or something else
                }
            }
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            File file = new File(PATH + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager",
                    "download ready in"
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                            + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }
    }

     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.craig.musicapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

.       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/jerrygarciahand"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchMusic"
            android:label="@string/search_music"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ConcertDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ItemListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AppInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_item_list" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does the device have connectivity? I'm not sure but I think this exception is also thrown when you try to make a network call without access to the network.

Comment: Are you using Wifi? If it's wifi? Are you connected in Wifi with Internet?

Comment: I do have connectivity and I am using wifi.  I checked by going to google and it worked just fine.

Comment: READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE do not exist and are simply ignored. You should remove those from the manifest as they don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am a dumb dumb and I figured it out.  Amazing what a night of sleep can do.

My url had "///" instead of "//".  Obviously this was causing an issue with the download.  Thank you for all your help and hopefully I won't get so sleep deprived next time and make such a silly error :).

Answer (score 1):

use this permission..in your android manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Sure can...  I just tested it in a browser and it worked.  Thank you for your help

http:///192.168.1.49:8888/The%20String%20Cheese%20Incident/2011-11-25%20Asheville_%20NC/03%20Sometimes%20A%20River.mp3

Comment: the link is a internal link within my network (192.168.1.49).  I am hosting the server internally.

Comment: the problem is connection timed out...it takes too much time to respond

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20212/discussion-between-mehul1000-and-user1815241)